# Protect azure website from data scraping

Tags: security, azure, web-scraping

I use azure for hosting my web app and lately i have noticed that my data is being scraped. I am wondering is there any built-in solution in Azure to protect web apps from data scraping.

If no, which tool is the best  for this purpose?

Or the only way is to protect data programmatically?

Comment: Actually it's pretty easy....first you need to include in your website `terms and conditions` that all kind of automations like web scraper-crawlers are forbidden, that is the easy part....and for the second one, which technologies are you using on your website....

Comment: I use ASP.NET MVC. Can you please clarify how to include terms and conditions in my website? From Azure Portal? Thanks...

Comment: You need to include another page like this one: https://www.facilitylive.com/terms-and-conditions/ ...this is for legal purposes....now for the technical part, if the coder that is trying to scrape data from your website is using a regular scraper-html-parser...then you can protect your data generating the content via javascript and ajax calls, but if the coder is using something more elaborated like Selenium WebDriver with PhantomJS for example, then there is little that you can do, maybe implementing some kind of blacklisting based on concurrent request from a suspicious ip can do the trick.

Comment: Take a look at what Troy Hunt did for protecting him against attacks.  You may find a few ideas there on how to blacklist suspicious IPs: https://www.troyhunt.com/azure-functions-in-practice/

Comment: If you don't want your content to be publically available, use authentication/authorisation - then you'll know who's accessing the data and you can start to control how which pieces, and how much they get access to (ie you can throttle, or implement policies to hide subsets of data for that caller).  If your website's all public and you've got anonymous access on, then whatever tricks you use to stop machines reading it, someone will always be able to come up with a way around them, as Hackerman says. Would be interested to understand the scenario a little more.